# How to simplify the next boolean algebra expresion?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

Im trying to do the next simplication of the next boolean algebra term
\$\bar{A}BC+A(\bar{A}C+B\bar{C})\$
In this way

\$\bar{A}BC+A\bar{A}C+AB\bar{C}\$

\$\bar{A}BC+0+AB\bar{C}\$

\$B(\bar{A}C+A\bar{C})\$

But whats next?
If I try to multiply by 1 , it ended changing the negation

\$B(A\bar{C}+\bar{A}C)\$\$

UPDATE
Based on an answer deleted and the DeMorgan Law
\$B(\bar{A}C+A\bar{C})\$

\$B(\overline{\bar{A}C+A\bar{C}})\$

\$B(\overline{\bar{A}C})(\overline{A\bar{C}})\$

\$B(A+\overline{C})(\overline{A}+C)\$

\$B(A\bar{A}+AC+\overline{AC}+C\bar{C})\$

\$B(AC+\overline{AC})\$

\$B(1)\$

\$B\$

Comment: The “simplification” from your update is wrong. Test it with ABC = 010 and you will see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some details are off in the application of De Morgans' laws.

De Morgans' laws state that

$$ \overline{(A + B)} = (\overline{A} * \overline{B}) $$
and
$$ \overline{(A * B)} = (\overline{A} + \overline{B})$$
(using the multiplication symbol * to stress what is being negated)

So in your case first of all

\$B(\overline{A}C + A\overline{C}) \neq B(\overline{A\overline{C}} + \overline{\overline{A}C})\$

But instead

\$\overline{A}C = \overline{A} * C = \overline{A} * \overline{\overline{C}} = \overline{(A + \overline{C})}\$

And

\$A\overline{C} = A * \overline{C} = \overline{\overline{A}} * \overline{C} = \overline{(\overline{A} + C)}\$

So

\$B(\overline{A}C + A\overline{C}) = B(\overline{(A + \overline{C})}+\overline{(\overline{A} + C)})\$

And applying De Morgan to the sum in the outer parentheses we get

\$B(\overline{(A + \overline{C})}+\overline{(\overline{A} + C)})=B(\overline{(A + \overline{C}) *  (\overline{A} + C)}) \$

That is

\$B(\overline{A\overline{A} +AC + \overline{C}\overline{A} + \overline{C}C}) = B(\overline{AC + \overline{C}\overline{A}})\$

Things start smelling a bit, looks like we might get back at the initial formula, let's see where we get from here

\$B(\overline{AC + \overline{C}\overline{A}}) = B(\overline{AC} * \overline{\overline{C}\overline{A}})\$

And similarly to what we did before, we get

\$\overline{AC} = (\overline{A} + \overline{C})\$

And

\$\overline{\overline{C}\overline{A}} = (C + A)\$

So

\$B(\overline{AC} * \overline{\overline{C}\overline{A}}) = B((\overline{A} + \overline{C}) * (A + C)) = B(\overline{A}A + \overline{A}C + \overline{C}A + \overline{C}C) = B(\overline{A}C + \overline{C}A)\$

That's it, we're back to square one.

As other have answered before you can see \$(\overline{A}C + A\overline{C})\$ as the exclusive or between \$A\$ and \$C\$, but you won't have it any simpler than that.

Answer (score 3):

\$ (\bar{A}C+A\bar{C})\$ is A xor C, so \$ B(\bar{A}C+A\bar{C})\$ its \$ B(A \oplus C) \$

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog true. But the equation cannot be simplified any further. Try ABC = 010 and you would see that your answer is just wrong.

Comment: Converting to XOR form usually does not simplify an equation. In the real world an XOR must be made from NOT/NAND/NOR gates anyway.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson not really. In CMOS you can directly implement an XOR gate as long as you have the input complements.